# Testing functions that produce files and print against existing files in Unittests

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I have two .py scripts that take take arguments from command line as inputs. One of these scipts produces another file with data and the other simply prints data to stdout.

I want to write unittests to test the contents of both the produced file for the first script and the data that is printed to stdout for the second script against existing files.

Any ideas on how I can do that? My plan is to compare the strings lines by line for the output file vs. existing file and printed output vs. existing file. But I am not sure how I can store the contents as neither script returns anything because I want to import the main methods from both scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You could collect all the stdout data in the one script by replacing the sys.stdout, and overriding the .write(), while you run the script. Then write() will be called every time your script writes to the stdout, and you can collect the data.

```
from io import StringIO
import sys
class Log(StringIO):
    stdout_data = []
    def write(self, string):
        stdout_data.append(string)

old_stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = Log() # Replace stdout with Log class
# RUN SCRIPT HERE
sys.stdout = old_stdout # Reset stdout to normal
```

Alternatively you can also use the subprocessing module to run your script and get the output.

```
from subprocessing import getoutput
stdout_data = getoutput('myscrpt.py')
```

When your other script writes to a file, you can then open the file in the default python way, and the file should be an iterable, and it should be possible to iterate over the file line by line. I think you could use zip() to then compare the lines from the stdout data and the file.

```
with open(file_path, mode='r') as f:
    for line1, line2 in zip(f, stdout_data):
        if line1 != line2:
            # fail the test
```

Comment: You should really use `unittest.mock` to replace stdout: